# Connecting to SQL Server over SSL and Getting Server Certificate

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl

I would like to connect to SQL Server configured for SSL on port 1433 and grab its certificate. I do not need to do any SQL, I just want to setup an SSL connection and get the SQL Server's cert.

The following code can get a web server cert, but can't get a SQL Server cert - the connection fails after a timeout period.

```
using (client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(Hostname, Port);
    var callback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    using (stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, callback))
    {
        stream.AuthenticateAsClient(Hostname);
    }
}
```

Do SQL Server clients have to use some initial negotiation to get the server to switch to SSL? In other words, does SQL Server do something similar to how STARTTLS works with SMTP?

What would I have to do to the above code to get the SQL Server to return its certificate?

Comment: Study FreeTDS' implementation.

Comment: Where are you specifying the port is 1433 in this code example?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I assume his `Port` variable is set outside the scope of his example code.

Comment: It's there now, got lost during some edits.

Comment: hi, is this a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

To quickly check SSL is configured on your SQL Server you can run the following:

SELECT session_id, encrypt_option
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections

You can also force encryption flag for SQL Server. You can do that in SQL Server Configuration manager

Good Luck, let me know if that helps.